# If Statements and Setting Variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, var

I'm trying to pass in `df1`, `df2`, `df3` & `df4` sequentially into the `parseTwoPoleBreakers` function. However, only `df1` is being ran. Is there something wrong with my `if` `elif` statements that causing  `df2`, `df3` & `df4` to not be passed into  the `parseTwoPoleBreakers` function?

```
i=0
for j in range(0,4):
    if j==0:
        df=df1
    elif j==1:
        df=df2
    elif j==2:
        df=df3
    else:
        df=df4
    #execute this for each dataframe
    while (i<7):
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(7,8,"ab",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(9,10,"bc",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(11,12,"ca",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
        i+=1
    #j+=1
    print j
```

Comment: You could try to print something in your elif statements. What have you done to debug your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass in df1, df2, df3 & df4 sequentially into the parseTwoPoleBreakers function

Your problem is most likely related to variable scoping inside the if statements or the fact the `while i < 7` isn't entered after `df1` because `i == 7`

Use a list instead for the `df` and did you mean to loop back over the 7 `i` values?

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    #execute this for each dataframe
    for i in range(7):
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(7,8,"ab",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(9,10,"bc",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
        parseTwoPoleBreakers(11,12,"ca",i,df)
        breakerid+=1
```

Comment: Welp, I'll look for someone to insult me for this stupid mistake :P